# Как работает backend на примере стеков graphQL и Apollo, nodejs, express?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, graphql, apollo-client

В сети очень мало информации на примере, помогающие установить связь между стеками GraphQL, Apollo, nodejs, express. У меня проблема в понимании того, как строится backend приложение, его шаги. Ниже я приведу несколько вопросов, показывающие в чём проблема.

1. Предположим, что есть Vue приложение. Данные подготовлены в формате JSON. Что делать дальше? Как это храниться в базе данных?
2. GraphQL это язык запросов, но на нём можно создавать и API.... Как это понять? Я считал, что он работает с готовым API, а он его ещё и создаёт?
3. Использование GraphQL на фронтенде и на бэкенде, есть Apollo на клиенте и на сервере... Как это всё понять? Где, что и когда используется, прошу краткое описание!
4. API можно сделать GraphQL, Apollo, nodejs, express... И при чём всё это может быть использовано самим GraphQL. Какая разница, где же всё таки делать?
5. Цитата из статьи: "Сервер GraphQL формирует основной компонент на стороне сервера и позволяет анализировать запросы, поступающие от клиентских приложений GraphQL. Apollo Server – наиболее часто используемая реализация спецификации GraphQL."    ВОПРОС - Зачем нужен Apollo Server если есть GraphQL сервер?

P.S. Прошу объяснить, как строится приложение?
К примеру...
Отправная точка: Сделали код на фронте. далее, исходя из структуры проекта, создаём JSON Файл... далее, по шагам
1) Нужно создать сервер, для того, чтобы .........
2) У нас есть данные, нужно связать клиента и сервера при помощи API, которое можно создать.......
3) .....

Comment: 1) Vue выполняется в браузере и к базе данных не имеет никакого отношения; 2) В этом самом API используется этот самый язык запросов; 3) Apollo Client и Apollo Server это две разные никак не связанные друг с другом библиотеки; 4) GraphQL это язык, Apollo это одна из реализаций языка, nodejs это платформа для запуска javascript-кода, express это веб-сервер работающий на платформе nodejs; 5) Нет никакого абстрактого «GrahpQL сервера», есть вполне конкретный Apollo Server как одна из реализаций сервера

Comment: Попробую объяснить, что мне нужно на изображении: https://prnt.sc/a5-T3b1kwGwT